# Javascript: Performing action once the next page has loaded?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am currently building a google extension and this is what I'm going for:

> Do something on awesome.page1.html then automatically press Next Page. When the new page has loaded, fill in a form's textfield.

My issue is that even though I know how to fill in the textfield, I don't quite know how to tell it to fill it in once page2 has loaded. It keeps trying to do everything on page 1.

This is what I'm trying but it's not working:

```
function addEffect() {
  document.getElementsByClassName("effect1 shine")[0].click();
  document.getElementsByClassName("nextPage BigButton")[0].click();
  nextStep();
}

function nextStep() {
  if(document.getElementsByClassName("myformTextField imageName") != undefined) { 
         alert('Page 2 is up.');
  } 

  else {
         alert('Page 1 is still up.');
         setTimeout("nextStep()", 250);
  }
}
```

I'm using an alert just for testing, and I keep getting the "Page 2 is up" even though it is still on page 1. I'm checking if an element, which is only present in page 2, is up. How could I make sure page2 is up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method I chose to go with was content script matches.

What I did was create two separate javascript files in my extension: 1.js and 2.js. When awesome.page1.html loads it will run 1.js and when page2.html loads it will run 2.js.

All I did in my manifest.json file is the following:

```
"content_scripts":[
        {"matches": ["http://awesome.page1.com/*"], "js": ["1.js"]},
        {"matches": ["http://page2.com/*"], "js": ["2.js"]}]
```

Answer (score 6):

The major issue you're going to run into is that JavaScript variables--including functions--don't persist from one page to another. Put another way, you can't write a function on one page and have it execute on the page that replaces it.

You could pass a URL variable or set a cookie for data persistence--or store settings on your server--but a straight JavaScript approach won't work.

Of course, there is a little trick that some folks use to load the entire DOM of the next page into a variable (using a variation on an XMLHttpRequest), apply the stored settings to the object in memory, and then replace most of the document body with most of the new DOM, but that's probably far more complicated than you need, and it has to conform to same-domain requirements.

Comment: Thanks Neil! In my manifest file my domain matches, has awesome.page1.com/* which is where I want to run my main js file (main.js) however this next page's domain is awesome2.diffpage.com/* Could that be the problem?

Comment: Again, your JS runs _only_ on the page where it's loaded... and then exits. Code on page 1 _won't_ (can't) run on page 2. As @rgthree noted, your function nextStep() is getting a nodeList, which can be empty but won't be undefined. The problem, for which I don't have a workaround, is that as soon as page 2 loads, your page-1 code, including all timeouts, disappears. Does that clarify?

Comment: Yes thank you Neil! Is there a way of maybe having 2 js files in my extension so that the second .js file reacts to this new subdomain page? An alternative that I see, is create a 2nd new extension, and just like this first one reacts to this subdomain, create a new extension that reacts to the second one. But I feel like there must be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code here:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("myformTextField imageName")
```

returns an empty array when it finds nothing, which is not `undefined`. Therefor, your first if condition will always be true, regardless if it finds your item or not.

Instead, check the length returned by `getElementsByClassName` or use `querySelector` and check for null

```
if (document.getElementsByClassName("myformTextField imageName").length) { ... }

// Or..
if (document.querySelector('.myformTextField.imageName') !== null) { ... }
```

Comment: Thanks rgthree but it's still returning the "it exists" on page 1 :/

Comment: Well, can't really debug your code from just your example here, but it doesn't negate the fact that your first condition will _always_ be true as it is.

Answer (score 0):

you should try to user **jquery** and the `$(document).ready(handler)`

this is really a best practice to ensure that the page is loaded before it tries to execute your commands 
http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: Can jquery be used in a chrome extension? Thanks Moises!